# Who controls a SE sites' looks and how?

Tags: discussion

This question is a bit more general but I like *photo SE*'s design the most. There are many 'default'-styled (not ugly but a bit unreadable and too uniform) beta SE sites out there. That made me wonder, just who is allowed to control a SE sites looks and exactly how it is done?

Photo SE also features a photo of the week in the header, how is this functionality put into the site's code?

**UPDATE 1** Who is capable of changing the default looks of an SE site and how does he do it?

Answer (score 4):

The design was done by Stack Exchange's very own in-house designer, and is maintained (and fixed) by them. The photo of the week is implemented by the moderators, who have control over the image and the text alongside.

Comment: +1. Does this work like this with the other SE sites? (I've updated my question a bit to reflect this aspect.)

Comment: All the sites run the same software, and none of them allow for non-Stack Exchange staff to change things like the CSS that define the layout.